# How do I solve my this windows 8 crashing only during the installation of a specific software?

Tags: windows, windows-8, crash

My computer works perfectly for all applications. Once, I installed Xilinx ISE 8.1 a few months back. Later on, I uninstalled it. Then, I tried to install it again. Since then I have been unable to install it; the pc just crashes always. Here's the report shown by "WhoCrashed.exe":[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I read countinously on Google but I have been unable to pinpoint to the cause as well as the remedy of my problem. There is no such kind of error for any applications ever. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Xilinx Is a notorious buggy software which is the reason hey discontinued support for the ide your using

Comment: share the dmp files so that we can debug them

Comment: @magicandre1981 Where are they located?

Comment: the are located in **C:\windows\minidump**

Comment: No such folder exists in my pc.